# How to install the driver of old graphics driver on linux[Radeon HD 8570 / R7 240/340 OEM]

Tags: linux, amd-radeon

This is my graphic card info

```
maple@maple-PC:~/Downloads/fglrx-15.302$ lshw -C display
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Oland [Radeon HD 8570 / R7 240/340 OEM]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 87
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:129 memory:90000000-9fffffff memory:a2c00000-a2c3ffff ioport:4000(size=256) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display
       description: Display controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:135 memory:a1000000-a1ffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:5000(size=64)
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

This is info of installing offical driver (AMD Radeon™ HD 8570 Linux x86_64)

```
maple@maple-PC:~/Downloads/fglrx-15.302$ ./amd-driver-installer-15.302-x86.x86_64.run 
Created directory fglrx-install.kxbtkH
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing AMD Proprietary Driver-15.302...........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

(gksu:16440): Gtk-WARNING **: 20:34:50.771: 无法在模块路径中找到主题引擎：“adwaita”，

(gksu:16440): Gtk-WARNING **: 20:34:50.771: 无法在模块路径中找到主题引擎：“adwaita”，
=====================================================================
 AMD  Proprietary Driver Installer/Packager 
=====================================================================

error: Detected X Server version 'XServer 1.20.0_64a' is not supported. Supported versions are X.Org 6.9 or later, up to XServer 1.10 (default:v2:x86_64:lib:XServer 1.20.0_64a:none:4.15.0-29deepin-generic:)
Installation will not proceed.

=====================================================================
 AMD  Proprietary Driver Installer/Packager 
=====================================================================

error: Detected X Server version 'XServer 1.20.0_64a' is not supported. Supported versions are X.Org 6.9 or later, up to XServer 1.10 (default:v2:x86_64:lib:XServer 1.20.0_64a:none:4.15.0-29deepin-generic:)
Installation will not proceed.

Removing temporary directory: fglrx-install.kxbtkH
```

This is system info

```
maple@maple-PC:~/Downloads/fglrx-15.302$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.15.0-29deepin-generic (pbuilder@zs-PC) (gcc version 7.3.0 (Debian 7.3.0-19)) #31 SMP Fri Jul 27 07:12:08 UTC 2018
```

So do I need to upgrade XServer?Or What else to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, if anything, you would need to *downgrade* Xorg server. fglrx 15.302 appears to require Xorg 1.16 (which was already outdated at that time – even back in the day when fglrx was "current", it was already known for never catching up with Xorg and always requiring a slightly older version).

You would probably need to downgrade so many packages that I would strongly recommend continuing to use the in-kernel `radeon` driver, as it stayed in development for much longer and (combined with modern Mesa OpenGL) really offers decent performance.